# How to avoid Inheritance in React?

Tags: inheritance, reactjs

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35949103/554807) Dan Abramov mentions that "Inheritance is an anti-pattern in React".

This was in relation to this code, which comes from a framework that I am starting to use:

```
class Home extends BasePage {

   render() {

      const { projects } = this.props;

      return (
         <div className="home-page container-fluid">
             {super.render()}
             <HomeLeftBar/>
             <HomePageHeader/>
             <ProjectsSummary/>
         </div>
      )
   }
 }
```

The reason that this component, which describes the content of a whole page, is inherited from BasePage is because there is common functionality - such as login idle timeout - that is implemented on BasePage.

What would be the correct way to deal with this, to avoid the "antipattern"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259405/react-es6-component-inheritance-working-but-not-recommended - Check that out?

Comment: You're right, my question duplicates that, thanks.